# Construir Tabla HTML comparando resultado de query con <th>

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Llevo un tiempo tratando de construir una tabla HTML con el resultado de una query que trae x ejemplo:

```
ID |   Fecha-Hora        | Id_Sala
----------------------------------
1  | 2019-05-01 10:00:00 |  2
2  | 2019-05-01 08:00:00 |  3
3  | 2019-05-01 08:00:00 |  4
4  | 2019-05-03 11:00:00 |  1
5  | 2019-05-03 11:00:00 |  2
6  | 2019-05-03 11:00:00 |  3
7  | 2019-05-04 09:00:00 |  3
8  | 2019-05-04 09:00:00 |  4
9  | 2019-05-04 10:00:00 |  5
```

El resultado que estoy tratando de obtener (sin exito hasta ahora) debiese ser algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que se imprima una "X en la celda que coincida la hora y el ID de la sala de cada registro. Los bloques de "Hora" son fijos.

Agradezco a los que me puedan dar una idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: que usas en backend.. traete todo el array armado ahi y hacé la lógica ahi

Comment: Qué código llevas hecho hasta ahora?

Answer (score -2):

De momento en 1 consulta no lo estoy pudiendo hacer te dejo esta otra opcion por si te sirve, seria basicamente hacer 3 queries, te adjunto el ejemplo:

```
/*Cosulta 1*/
select id_salida from tabla group by id_salida;
/*Cosulta 2*/
select TIME(fecha_hora) from tabla group by TIME(fecha_hora);
/*Cosulta 3*/
select DATE(fecha_hora), TIME(fecha_hora), id_salida from tabla;
```

Luego el codigo PHP(nose que lenguaje usas asique es a modo ejemplo) seria algo como esto para armar la estructura adecuada:

```
//Lo populas con la consulta 1
$id_salidas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
//Lo populas con la consulta 2
$horarios = ["08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00"]; 
$childrens = [];
foreach($horarios as $horario){
    foreach($id_salidas as $id_salida){
        $childrens[$horario][$id_salida] = null;
    }
}
$array_final = [];
//Lo populas con la consulta 3
$query_result_3 = ....
//Recorremos consulta 3
foreach($query_result_3 s $result){
    if(!array_key_exists($result->fecha,$array_final)){
        $array_final[$result->fecha] = $childrens;
    } 
    $array_final[$result->fecha][$result->hora][$result->id_salida] = true; 
}
```

Esto te puede servir principalmente si no son muchos datos o tiene paginado, sino tendrias que hacerlo todo en una query si o si, spero que sirva ni bien tenga la respuesta en SQL hare el update, saludos!

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, pues si dejan de ser accesibles la información se pierde, edita y agrega todo lo relevante aquí, mira [answer]

Comment: Ahi trate de arreglar lo que me comentas, gracias